# Magento Cache Warming

Tags: magento, caching

My team and I are rapidly launching new stores and views on Magento Enterprise Edition but we're running into an issue with caching. To be clear, the caching part itself works great. We have several complex products that take about 17 seconds to build, but after its cached the pages loads in 300ms, which is awesome! Unfortunately, if we clear the cache under any serious load (high traffic) we seem to be experiencing a cache miss storm, where every page request is trying to populate the cache, causing our webhead to stall out with load averages above 50.

Do you have any suggestions for avoiding this? Are there documented best practices for pre-warming a cache for new code deployments or even just content and configuration changes?

This could be related, so I'll include it: After clicking the button to refresh the cache and before the refreshing process is complete most pages on the front end die with 500 error codes and seemingly random error messages. Any idea what might cause that?

Comment: The size of the cache is really irrelevant to the question. As someone who is relatively new to Magento I'm looking for a recommended way of warming the magento cache. Additionally, an explanation for why a cold or halfway empty cache would cause 500 errors with seemingly random, unrelated messages. A cache miss should simply regenerate the information and add it to the cache.

Comment: I heard about a varnish configuration setting, where you can send the user "old data" (so he get's a fast answer) and send a request to the server between varnish and apache/nginx so the cache warms up, and the miss is from the varnish, so no problem. But I have no idea, what this setting is. I have no idea from varnish :)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution to warm up a cache after a CMS Block is saved. You may take the inspiration of this solution to do the same for different cases (product save, CMS block, CMS Page, Category Save, etc)

This piece of code can be triggered after a CMS Block save by using an observer `cms_block_save_after`:

```
/**
 * Clean targeted cache block and warmup if content is provided
 */
public function clearBlockHtmlCache(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();

    $id = $block->getCacheKey();

    // Remove only specific cache block
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getFrontend()->remove(strtoupper($id));

    // no print, it's ok just warmup cache with filters processing
    $block->toHtml();
}
```